# Interbase Ext. Not Working?

Tags: php, windows, apache

Installed Apache 2.2.19 and PHP 5.3.6 When I uncommented the extension for the php_interbase.dll apache breaks. The dll is in the php/ext/ path and is pointing to it correctly. the extension_dir directive points to the same path and other extensions work fine.

```
Apache Error=httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
```

Answer (score 0):

After hours…. Of searching I discovered that the version of php I am using did not include 2 needed DLLs (gds34.dll and fbclient.dll). I added them to the php directory and it worked. I was aware of the gds34.dll but not of the fbclient.dll, that one was the missing dll that the readme file does not specifically mention it.